# Jenkins Workflow plugin Maven "No compiler is provided in this environment"

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow

I have a Workflow job with the following Groovy code segment:

```
def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn install"
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

I have installed JDK in "Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System" and gave the name "JAVA_HOME". When a run a "Freestyle project" job to test the installation:

```
echo "JDK: $JAVA_HOME"
```

The output is good:

```
JDK: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JAVA_HOME
```

I also tried restarting Jenkins but it didn't help. Please advise.

---

FYI, I started to use the following fix by changing the Workflow code like this:

```
def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
def javaHome = tool 'JAVA_HOME'

sh "JAVA_HOME=$javaHome $mvnHome/bin/mvn install"
```

I don't know if this is a correct solution or a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Your final script looks correct. Maven generally requires a full JDK to run, not just a JRE. If your build slave does not already have one in its `$PATH` then you can use the `tool` step to modify `$PATH` and/or `$JAVA_HOME` to point to it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but Jenkins recommends doing it this way:

```
withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${ tool 'JAVA_HOME' }", "PATH+MAVEN=${tool 'M3'}/bin"]) {

    sh "mvn install"

}
```

You can see it here: [Jenkins Pipeline Examples](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/). It works for me